# Display count of all no and yes in group by table name

Tags: mysql

I have a table like..

```
id cluster status
1 cluster_0 yes
2 cluster_0 no
3 cluster_0 yes
4 cluster_0 yes
5 cluster_1 no
6 cluster_5 yes
7 cluster_0 yes
8 cluster_8 no
...
...
...
```

I tried to see the yes count and no count of all the clusters..

For yescount I can use a query like

```
SELECT cluster,count(*) as yescount FROM `cluster` WHERE status='yes' group by cluster

cluster   yescount
cluster_0 11
cluster_1 30
cluster_2 6
cluster_3 1
cluster_4 20
```

But, how can I display nocount side by the yescount simply like..

```
cluster   yescount nocount
cluster_0 11       5
cluster_1 30       10
cluster_2 6        20 
cluster_3 1        3
cluster_4 20       10
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use case based aggregation

In MySQL, when status='yes' is evaluated it returns 1 for true 0 for false
so we can use sum(status='yes') to get yes count.

```
select cluster, 
       sum(status='yes') as yescount,
       sum(status='n')  as nocount
from Table1
group by cluster
```